# How to detect intersecting nodes of children of other SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I hope you all can help with this. I'm working on app of a board game. I have hex shaped tiles which are called randomly and laid out at the start of the game. Each of these tiles has four sides with a value of 1 and the other two sides have values of 2 and 3.

Each tile is a SKSpriteNode with transparent rectangle Nodes on the edges. There are 5 different types of tiles and they need to be separate Sprites with child nodes because in addition to being randomly laid out they area also randomly rotated. So I need to know programmatically which tile edges are touching which edges of other tiles.

Like this:

https://app.box.com/s/nnym97st3xmrsx979zchowdq1qwsmpoo

*(I tried to post an image of what I'm trying to accomplish, but apparently I don't have a high enough of a rating.)* ;-)

For example: If a "2" is touching a "3", etc.

I first tried Collision detection, but of course that only works with dynamic, moving objects.

I tried an IF statement to compare if the other nodes were touching and then remembered that the coordinates where specific to the Parent Node, so that didn't work.

I then tried intersectsNode, but that seems to only work with nodes under the same parent.
I am currently working with convertPoint in order to get the coordinates to match the scene and thus be comparable. But I can't seem to get it work the way I need.

There must be something simple that I am not seeing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not simple.

One solution would be to start all your shapes slightly spaced out from each other. Add invisible child nodes with physics bodies to all six sides and give each physics body an appropriate category based on their rating (1, 2 or 3).

When you start the game, move all the outer nodes into their proper position (sides touching) by using whatever movement method your prefer. This will give you contact messages as each hex side touches another. The contact messages will tell you what side number is touching its neighbor.

The exact coding of this idea depends on your current code, game play, etc...

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I did try something similar by having the child nodes all move just a few pixels upon loading, but it didn't yield any results. The nodes would have already overlapped when initially placed, could that have prevented the collision detection? If so, I could adjust it by adapting your method above and simply having the child nodes move from the center of the hex to the outer edges. That may be easier than having to move all the hexes themselves. Thank you very much! I'll give that a test in the morning. ;-)

Comment: @Freedlun - Moving the hexes is not that hard. If you know the ending positions of each one, you can use a SKAction moveTo x,y over duration. The hexes coming together movement might even give your game a cool looking startup animation.

Comment: True. In fact that's exactly what I did, though I did it with the childern. Using SKActions I move the Edge sprites from (0, 0) to their locations and it works perfectly! Contact is detected. Now I can move on with other aspects of the game. Thanks so much!